# Generate full paths from relative paths in python efficiently

Tags: python, optimization, path

I have the following array of strings, which are representing relative paths and their relation to each other.

```
array = ['/NetworkSettings/agentsInfos/AgentInfos', '/AgentInfos/interfacesSettings/InterfaceSetting', '/InterfaceSetting/networkStack/NetworkStack', '/BaseConfig/networkSettings/NetworkSettings']
```

I want to generate the full paths e.g

```
/BaseConfig/networkSettings/agentsInfos/interfacesSettings/networkStack/NetworkStack
/BaseConfig/networkSettings/agentsInfos/interfacesSettings/InterfaceSetting
/BaseConfig/networkSettings/agentsInfos/AgentInfos
```

I have come with the following solution but it is not efficient enough and it's generating all the combinations of paths, not only the full ones:

```
array1 = ['/NetworkSettings/agentsInfos/AgentInfos', '/AgentInfos/interfacesSettings/InterfaceSetting', '/InterfaceSetting/networkStack/NetworkStack', '/BaseConfig/networkSettings/NetworkSettings']

def func(array1, count = 5):
    
    while(count != 0):
        for i in range(len(array1)):
            for j in range(len(array1)):
                if i != j and array1[i].split('/')[len(array1[i].split('/')) - 1] == array1[j].split('/')[1]:
                    if '/'.join(array1[i].split('/')[:len(array1[i].split('/')) - 1]) + '/' + '/'.join(array1[j].split('/')[2:]) not in array1:
                        array1.append('/'.join(array1[i].split('/')[:len(array1[i].split('/')) - 1])  + '/' + '/'.join(array1[j].split('/')[2:]))
        count -= 1
    return array1

func(array1, 5)
```

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: You're trying to match up the last element of one path with the first element of another?

Comment: You could represent your data as a directed acyclic graph instead of an array. Then start with every terminal node and combinatorically recreate every possible path. In the end the code will be more efficient, however you need to parse your data in a graph first.

Comment: An efficient way to do that matching would be to put either the first or the last component as keys in a dict; then you'll be able to find it quickly

Comment: @sabik yes, that is want I want to do.